# consultas de campos en datatables con modal

Tags: php, modal

tengo un pequeño problema. Estoy creando un módulo de servicio técnico y debo registrar los detalles de cada acción realizada a los equipos, los cuales tengo ordenados en un index con páginacion por medio de datatables y salida por Json pues bn necesito enviar el ID de cada equipo a un modal para que me cargue automáticamente el nombre del equipo, pero solo me muestra el primer registro de la tabla.
necesito que para cada registro de equipo en soporte tecnico me permita cargar los detalles de las acciones realizadas en ese equipo, esto con el fin de manejar un historial de detallado de todos los trabajos que se le han realizado.

```js
$sTabla = "soporte";
 
 /* Array que contiene los nombres de las columnas de la tabla*/
 $aColumnas = array( 'cod_serv_tec', 'cod_eq', 'fal_eq', 'nom_emp_cont', 'telf_emp' );

 
 /* columna indexada */
 $sIndexColumn = "cod_serv_tec";
 
 // Paginacion
 $sLimit = "";
 if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
 {
  $sLimit = "LIMIT ".$_GET['iDisplayStart'].", ".$_GET['iDisplayLength'];
 }
 
 
 //Ordenacion
 if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
 {
  $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
  {
   if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
   {
    $sOrder .= $aColumnas[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
    ".$_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] .", ";
   }
  }
  
  $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
  if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
  {
   $sOrder = "";
  }
 }
 
 //Filtracion
 $sWhere = "";
 if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
 {
  $sWhere = "WHERE (";
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
  {
   $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
  }
  $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
  $sWhere .= ')';
 }
 
 // Filtrado de columna individual 
 for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
 {
  if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
  {
   if ( $sWhere == "" )
   {
    $sWhere = "WHERE ";
   }
   else
   {
    $sWhere .= " AND ";
   }
   $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%' ";
  }
 }
 
 
 //Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
 FROM   $sTabla
 $sWhere
 $sOrder
 $sLimit
 ";
 $rResult = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
 
 /* Data set length after filtering */
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
 ";
 $rResultFilterTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
 $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_array();
 $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
 
 /* Total data set length */
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
 FROM   $sTabla
 ";
 $rResultTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
 $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_array();
 $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
 
 /*
  * Output
 */
 $output = array(
 "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
 "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
 "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
 "aaData" => array()
 );
 
 while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_array())
 {



  $row = array();
  
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
  {
   if ( $aColumnas[$i] == "version" )
   {
    /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
    $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
   }
   else if ( $aColumnas[$i] != ' ' )
   {
    /* General output */
    $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
   }
  }
  
  $row[] = "<td><a href='modificar.php?cod_serv_tec=".$aRow['cod_serv_tec']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a></td>";
  $row[] = "<td><a href='#' data-href='eliminar.php?cod_serv_tec=".$aRow['cod_serv_tec']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></td>";
  $row[] = "<td><a href='#' data-href='Index.php?cod_eq=".$aRow['cod_eq']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalNuevo' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' ></span></a></td>";
  
  $output['aaData'][] = $row;
 }
 
 echo json_encode( $output );
```

```html
<?php
     
     //$cod = $_GET['cod_eq'];
      $sql = "SELECT s.cod_serv_tec, s.cod_eq, e.cod_eq, e.nom_eq FROM soporte s, equipo e where e.cod_eq=s.cod_eq ";
          $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

     if ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
      {
       $codigo = $rs["cod_eq"];
       $nombre = $rs['nom_eq'];
      }
     

     

    ?>
  </td> 
<!--modal de registro de actividades ("modal-sm"=para colocar el modal en small)-->

  <div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" align="center"><img src="../../Imagenes/Logo1.gif" width="34" height="23" />Agregar Servicio</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">



          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $codigo; ?>" name="" id="codigo"  readonly>
           <label>Nombre del Equipo</label>
           <input type="text" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" name="" id="nombre" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>

           <label>Fecha y hora</label>
           <input type="text" name="" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima'); echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");?>" id="fecha" class="form-control input-sm" readonly>

           <label>Nombre del Tecnico</label>
           <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Nombre del Tecnico" id="nom_tec" class="form-control input-sm" title="Ingrese el Nombre del Tecnico">

           <label>Telefono</label>
           <input type="number" name="" id="telefono" placeholder="Telefono del Tecnico" class="form-control input-sm" title="Ingresar el Numero Telefonico del Tecnico">

           <label>Contador Inicial</label>
           <input type="text" name="" id="inicial" placeholder="Contador inicial del Equipo" class="form-control input-sm" title="Ingrese el Numero de Contador Antes de realizar el Servicio">

           <label>Contador Final</label>
           <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Contador Final del Equipo" id="final" class="form-control input-sm" title="Ingrese el Numero de Contador Despues de realizar el Servicio">

           <label>Detalle</label>
           <textarea name="" id="detalle" class="form-control" size="25" placeholder="Detalles del Servicio Realizado" title="Indique los Detalles del Servicio Realizado"></textarea>
           
           <label>Cambio de Componente</label>
           <input type="text" name="" id="cambio" placeholder="Componente Reemplazado" class="form-control input-sm" title="Indique si Realizo Algun Cambio de Componentes">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="guardarnuevo">
          Agregar
          </button>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Si alguien ha tenido ese mismo problema y me pudiese ayudar lo agradecería.

Comment: Una pregunta pretende hacer que cada id usuario o trabajador tenga  los datos correspondientes verdad .

Comment: no, quiero que al hacel click el el icono de mas me genere el modal de registro de actividad,pero que se cargue el nombre del equipo el cual seleccionaron.

Comment: Cuando llegue a casa  le miro haber que solución. Le damos de toda manera pon como tiene. La base de datos como lo tiene diseñada?